# ViewModel with Collection of another ViewModel - Can AutoMapper Help Me Here?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class CreateReviewViewModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public decimal Score { get; set; }
   public ICollection<RecommendationViewModel> Recommendations { get; set; }
}
```

So, the first two are basic native types - easy.

The third property is a collection of another ViewModel:

```
public class RecommendationViewModel
{
   public RecommendationType RecommendationType { get; set; }
   public bool IsRecommendedFor { get; set; }
}
```

`RecommendationType` is an `enum` in my domain model, which has `byte` values representing a different "recommendation".

On my `[HttpGet]` action, i do this:

```
var model = new CreateReviewViewModel
{
   Recommendations = SomeMethodWhichLoopsThroughTheEnumMembersAndCreatesTheModel();
}
return View(model);
```

So i end up with a list of `RecommendationViewModel`, with the `bool` properties set to `false`.

Then on my View, i use **EditorTemplates:**

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recommendations)`

Which calls a custom Editor template that renders a label and checkbox for the two properties. Cool.

So - there's the background, which hopefully makes sense.

How do i map that ViewModel to a `Review` domain model in the `[HttpPost]` action?

The part of the `Review` object looks like this:

```
public class Review
{
   public bool IsRecommendedForA { get; set; }
   public bool IsRecommendedForB { get; set; }
   // etc
}
```

I'm currently doing custom mapping like this:

```
var review = new Review();
review.IsRecommendedForA = this.Recommendations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RecommendationType == RecommendationType.A).IsRecommendedFor;
review.IsRecommendedForB = this.Recommendations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RecommendationType == RecommendationType.B).IsRecommendedFor;
```

Which is very tedious.

Can i do the above with AutoMapper?

Of course, i **could** just add all the different RecommendationType's as basic properties on the ViewModel instead of a collection, but then my View's become complicated, and i can't use EditorTemplates to implicitly loop through the collection - i would have to write out `Html.EditorFor` for each property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one **possible solution**:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CreateReviewViewModel, Review>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.IsRecommendedForA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsRecommendedFor(RecommendationType.A)))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.IsRecommendedForB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsRecommendedFor(RecommendationType.B)));
```

Where `IsRecommendedFor` is a hook property, using the LINQ expression stated earlier in my question to work out if the model contains the property, and it's checked.

Which is better than the manual left-to-right, but still not great.

I've taken a look at custom converters/resolvers, but none take additional parameters (e.g resolve from this to this, using this parameter also), so i can't see how i can use them.

I'll go with this for now, but hoping someone knows how to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you need to store those boolean values all separately, for every possible enum value? A flag means you could have multiple types enabled... I feel like this would be better:

```
public class Review {
    public RecommendationType Types { get; set; }

    public bool IsReviewFor(RecommendationType types) {
        // bitwise comparison, check if the flags 
        // given are in the Types property also
    }
}
```

Easier mapping, less code, more extensible when adding/removing new types.

```
myReview.IsReviewFor(RecommendationType.X | RecommendationType.Y | RecommendationType.Z)
```

Comment: "Review" is a POCO used by Entity Framework to persist to my table called "Review", which is a flat table - having all those fields at the single flat level is for performance reasons.